# 2011 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2011 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://android.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Is this ... real?  No warning, and the election page doesn't have any details about whether we're adding to us pro tems or if we have to run again or what....

Comment: If the past is any guide, Pro Tem Moderators need to nominate themselves if they want to stay on as moderators.

Comment: And Shog9 did recently say "stand by for news" when I asked about elections.

Comment: @MatthewRead you should have received an email...  Al is correct, these are official elections - pro tems need to nominate if they'd like to continue moderating.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Hmm, nope.  My spam filter's been overactive lately but there's nothing there.  Thanks for confirming though.

Comment: @Rebecca: No e-mail here either.

Comment: Yikes!  That's not good.  We're looking into it.